# Hibernate disable default behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem with my Hibernate making assumptions on what to call columns.

Specifically, when I do a @ManyToOne field, where I refer to a column in the other Table.
What happens is that, If I do not enter a @JoinColumn annotation as well, it maps the field with an underscore in it's name.

For example, i have this class:

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;

     private String username;
     private String password;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userFK")
     private List<TwitterAccount> twitterAccounts;

     /* GETTERS & SETTERS OMITTED */
}
```

And then I have the TwitterAccount class:

```
@Entity
public class TwitterAccount extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User userFK;
}
```

What happens is that when it tries to get the Twitter accounts for a certain user, I get the exception: `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'twitteracc1_.userFK_id' in 'field list'`

Look at what it tries to map the userFK to: `userFK_id`. Of course it doesn't exist! I haven't given it that name.

So the question comes down to: **Is it possible to turn off this functionality?** (The functionality that turns the column name into 'field_'foreignkey')

I am aware that using `@JoinColumn(name = "userFK")` would solve it, but I'd rather turn it off instead.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default as specified by the JPA specification

> The concatenation
>   of the following: the name
>   of the referencing relationship
>   property or field of the referencing
>   entity or embeddable class;
>   "*"; the name of the referenced
>   primary key column. If there is no
>   such referencing relationship
>   property or field in the entity, or if
>   the join is for an element collection,
>   the join column name is
>   formed as the concatenation of the
>   following: the name of the entity;
>   "*"; the name of the referenced
>   primary key column.

In hibernate this is implemented in a `NamingStrategy` in this case the `EJB3NamingStrategy`. You can implement your own version of this deciding whatever you want to use. But that will probably only complicate/confuse people (which might expect the standards to apply).

Comment: Hi again, yes I am aware of that. But if the only solution is to write your own implementation of a NamingStrategy, I'd rather leave it be. Thanks again tho!